# how to recover image or other file from ipfs?

Tags: ipfs, js-ipfs

I have a cid returned by ipfs.add api, and i want get the file(image) but i can't restore the picture even i can get the Uint8Array, and I have read the [api docs](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#ipfsgetipfspath-options), but i still can't get it.

I want to know how to manipulate data to recover my picture or just get the pic using cid.

here is my code

```js
    let chunks = '';
    const cid = 'something hash';

    for await (const buf of ipfs.get(cid)) {
        chunks += buf;
    }
    fs.writeFileSync('./img.jpg', chunks);
```